# Adding to SortedLinkedList using nodes

Tags: linked-list, nodes, compareto, sorting

im making a SortedLinkedList, I'm trying to add lets say 10 integers of different value so I can run some asssert tests. But I'm having a problem adding them so they are already sorted when they arrive to the LinkedList, I tried using the `curr.info.compareTo(x) > 0` for instance, but I'm having trouble making the correct else/if statements so it sorts them when they are added.

This code has 4 classes, I can provide more if its unclear.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Best regards,

Victor

```
public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {

    /*  Easy operations for a linked list

    add(x): Searching for the place where the element x is to be added must
        take place in the calling routine. This must set previous to
        point to the node AFTER which the new element is to be inserted.
        curr is set to point to the new element.

    remove(): The curr element is removed from the list. Searching for this 
        element must take place in the calling routine. This must set 
        curr to point to the element to be removed. After removal curr
        points to the element following the removed one. 

    isEmpty(): checks for an empty list

    endOfList(): checks whether curr has reached and passed the end of the list 

    retrievecurr(): return the info part of the curr element.

    reset(): resets the list so that curr points to the first element

    succ(): an iterator, moves curr one step forward

    Note that when a class implements the interface Iterable<T> then
    it can be the target of the "foreach" statement. See IterationExample.java */


    private Node start, curr, prev;
    public SortedLinkedList() {
        curr = null;     // the curr position in the list
        start = null;    // the first element
        prev = null;     // the node before curr
    }
    public void add(T x) {
        if (start == null) {            // if start == null, insert a first element into an empty list
            Node newNode = new Node();  // create the new element, info and link are set to null.
            newNode.info = x;           // and assign the data given as parameter. The link is left as null            
            start = newNode;            // start is updated to point to the new element
            curr = start;               // curr is updated to point to the new first (and only) element
        } else if (prev == null) { // a new first element is inserterd into a non-empty list
            Node newNode = new Node();  // a new node is created ...
            newNode.info = x;           // and assigned the data given as parameter
            newNode.link = start;       // and linked before the old first element 
            start = newNode;            // start is updated to point to the new first element
            curr = newNode;             // curr is updated to point to the new first element
        } else { // a new element is inserted last (if prev.link == null) or between prev and curr
            Node newNode = new Node();  // create a new node 
            newNode.info = x;           // assign it the data given as parameter 
            newNode.link = prev.link;   // link it before curr ...
            prev.link = newNode;        // ... and after previous
            curr = newNode;             // update curr to point to newNode      
        }
    } // add*
}
```